# TFS 2013 gated checked in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2013

I want to set up a gated checked-in policy for my project using TFS 2013 and VS 2013. I want to set up a process that before dev, checked in Unit Test and Code Quality analysis should run.
I want to use Nunit for unit Test purposes.
Can anybody share an example of how to set up the process?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What did you try so far, and how did the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: Do you want a gated check-in on build, or do you want a Check-in policy?The first does what every checks you configure before the code is commited, otherwise it's left on the shelf, the second runs in VS that ensures the developer has done a build / test on their machine - and can more easily be bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to implement first option i.e. gated check-in which allow developer to check-in code if all Tests are successful only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new build definition with a "Trigger of Gated" like so:

[image: Trigger set to Gated]

Then goto the "Process" tab and set it so that it does as many of the following as you like:

1. [Run Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138(v=vs.120).aspx).
2. [Perform Code Analysis always](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hkamel/archive/2013/10/24/visual-studio-2013-static-code-analysis-in-depth-what-when-and-how.aspx).
3. Pass MSBuild args to [treat warnings as error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8b19172-dc67-4474-8fd1-d7c4dec75b98/can-switch-warning-message-to-error-message-in-msbuild?forum=msbuild)s.

[image]

Comment: Thanks DaveShaw!! Is it possible to integrate FXCop and Nunit in Gated check-in OR any other tools?

Comment: Yes, FXCop is just code analysis, nUnit tests just need configuring to run on the build server, I'm sure there's a nunit on TFS guide somewhere.